# Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: mysql

I tried to insert values on this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `textos`.`textos` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre_textos` VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL,
  `texto` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL,
  `id_usuarios` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_usuarios` (`id_usuarios` ASC),
  INDEX `id_usuarios_2` (`id_usuarios` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `textos_ibfk_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuarios`)
    REFERENCES `textos`.`usuarios` (`id`)
   )
```

and mysql throws me this error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate
>   entry '17' for key 'id_usuarios'

Someone could help me?
I hope what I have requested is possible

Comment: Why do you have both an index and a unique index on the same field?

Comment: Remove `unique` constraint ion `id_usuarios`

Comment: @Kickstart i really don't know why it did that. it is my first time using foreign keys. But I could change it. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: @Delphine, Thanks! It worked.

Comment: @RobMacías perfect ! :)

Comment: So wait... you have a UNIQUE index on id_usarios... so they can only have one textos per id_usarios by design.  Is that want you want or do you want to allow multiple textos per usuarios? if you want to allow multiple, then Delphine is correct.  if you only want to allow 1 textos per usuarios then the error is justified!